# onReceive never getting called

Tags: java, android, sms

Below is my Java code and my XML code. Can someone please tell me why my `onReceieve` method is never getting called.

Java:

```
public class PopUPSMS extends Activity {

    String RECEIVE_SMS = "RECEIVE_SMS";

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PopUPSMS";

    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(RECEIVE_SMS));
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smith.johnathan.phone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PopUPSMS"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to register receiver for "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED". I have updated the answer you asked yesterday and it describes correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(RECEIVE_SMS));
```

You have registered your broadcast receiver with the string "RECEIVE_SMS". The IntentFilter should be of a form of an action. With your declaration:

```
static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
```

you will have:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(ACTION));
```

You  can have a look at the [Api demos Manifest](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/AndroidManifest.html) for the XML declaration

Comment: thnks cchenson it works now!  but i still cant get the alert box up

Comment: See your other post. I have added an answer. According to the doc, it s not possible.

Comment: @ccheneson The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission (in the tutorial you mention) to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks and receiving outright rejections with either no explanations or generic feedback. Any ideas on how to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use receiver as an inner class. Create a separate one.

Comment: sorry vladimir I dont think you are right. I found alot of examples that do it my work. it has to be something!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to specify that you want to receive SMS in your manifest?

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name=".MyApp"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>

</application>
```